# How to insert the auto incremented field id of mysql in php and update the id of one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables called run_test and file_email.I want to insert the run_test table using php.It is working fine.When I update the run_test , id field also should get updated in file_email table.

I am not getting how to use insert statement in php for this.

While creating table, I have used this queries.

```
create table run_test(id int not null auto_increment,url varchar(255),gh_url varchar(255),platform varchar(255),machine_size varchar(255),browser varchar(255),image_id varchar(255), security_id varchar(255),instance int,timer varchar(255),protocol varchar(255),concurrency int,rampup int,iteration int ,time_out int, cache varchar(255), primary key(id));


create table file_email(id int primary key  ,filename varchar(255),email varchar(255), foreign key(id) references run_test(id));
```

And I have created a trigger,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggered_from_runtest 
    BEFORE insert ON run_test
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  file_email
    SET file_email.id = new.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In php, to insert id field of `run_test` using null or without entering anything it is auto incremented in `run_test` field but it is not taking updated auto increment value in `file_email` table even though  I have created a trigger. It is taking 0 in that field.

In php I have used like this,

```
insert into run_test(url,gh_ur,....)values('www.google.com','www.yajana.com',..............);
```

and this also I have tried,

```
insert into run_test(id,url,gh_ur,....)values(null,'www.google.com','www.yajana.com',..............);
```

In `run_test` it get incremented but not in `file_email`.

How can I do this?

run_test table:

[image]

file_email table is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to correct three things to get what you are expecting.

1) Alter your run_test table's id column by specifying integer range (`alter table run_test modify column id int(11) auto_increment`
).

2) Then change your trigger like given below, which will insert new entry's id into your file_email table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggered_from_runtest 
    AFTER insert ON run_test
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
set @lastId=(select id from run_test order by id desc limit 1);
    INSERT INTO  file_email(id) values(@lastId);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

3) Remove id given in run_test table's insert query(php query) and run your file.

You will get your output!!!!!

Comment: Thank you  so much :) . But, in trigger statement I removed the <br> apart from first and last last line. It is working fine.

Comment: Ya i forgot to remove. now i have edited that thank you for let me know!!!

Comment: To vijay ,I have another doubt here.

Comment: I have another doubt here.

Comment: To vidya:  whats your doub't hope i can help u

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger for auto_increment, if the db schemea is setup correctly on add it will auto int for you.

I suggest checking your database. You are doing this the hardway.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html